# Gumstix Overo wifi drops continously

Tags: embedded-linux, wifi, bitbake, gumstix

I am using Gumstix overo and from the past many days I am unable to get my Wifi working correctly.

I followed the instructions from [Gumstix Overo Wifi](http://www.blogdugas.net/?p=246) and [Overo Wifi](http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=Overo_Wifi) to set correct parameters in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf.

/etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# Wireless interfaces
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      pre-up wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
      down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
    ctrl_interface_group=0
    update_config=1
    eapol_version=1
    ap_scan=1
    fast_reauth=1

    network={
            ssid="xxxxxx"
            proto=WPA
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
            pairwise=CCMP TKIP
            group=CCMP TKIP
            scan_ssid=1
            psk="xxxxx"
            priority=10
    }
```

After setting up and running `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0`  i constantly get this message:

**[ 1176.528778] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain** 

 **[ 2155.687255] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain** 

 **[ 1175.293609] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain**

My `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

My lsmod looks like this:

root@overo:~# lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
libertas_sdio          16484  0 
libertas               99993  1 libertas_sdio
firmware_class          6920  2 libertas_sdio,libertas
ipv6                  252525  22 
cfg80211              172644  1 libertas
rfkill                 17524  3 cfg80211
lib80211                5138  1 libertas
mt9v032                 7169  1 
omap3_isp             132270  0 
v4l2_common             8681  2 omap3_isp,mt9v032
ads7846                10528  0 
videodev               98880  3 omap3_isp,mt9v032,v4l2_common
media                  12853  3 omap3_isp,mt9v032,videodev
```

I am using yocto project for gumstix cloned from https://github.com/gumstix/Gumstix-YoctoProject-Repo

It would be great help if I could get any inputs where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for wifi drop is the Network manager. By disabling it we can run `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` without any interference from the NetworkManager.

or Another workaround is this which is quite successful:

After creating SD card with proper Image on, do not unmount the partitions.

**Install a Custom systemd Service**

To bring up the wireless interface on boot, you will need to create and install a custom systemd service on the microSD card.

- In the rootfs partition, create a new service script:

  `$sudoedit /media/rootfs/etc/systemd/system/network-wireless@.service`
- Copy and paste the following into the file:

  `Description=Wireless network connectivity (%i)`

  `Wants=network.target`

  `Before=network.target`

  `BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device`

  `After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device`

  `[Service]`

  `Type=oneshot`

  `RemainAfterExit=yes`

  `ExecStart=/sbin/ifconfig %i up`

  `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -i %i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

  `ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient %i`

  `RestartSec=1min`

  `Restart=on-failure`

  `ExecStop=/sbin/ifconfig %i down`

  `[Install]`

  `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Save this file.

- Because we are editing these files on a development machine, the normal systemd method of enabling services (systemctl) will not work. To enable our new service:

  ~ Change into the multi-user.target.wants directory on the root filesystem:

  `$cd /media/rootfs/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

  ~ Create a symbolic link to enable the service:

  **Overo Series COMs**

  `$sudo ln -s ../network-wireless@.service network-wireless@wlan0.service`

Finally, edit the `wpa_supplicant` configuration file:

```
$sudoedit /media/rootfs/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Change it to look like the following:

```
network={
    ssid="Your Network's SSID"
    psk="Your WPA2 Passkey"
}
```

Save the file.

Unmount the partitions on the microSD card.

**SSH Into Your System**

1) If you don't know the ip `$ssh root@overo.local`
  
 2) If you know the IP address  `$ssh root@192.xx.xx.xx.local`

Comment: I had to add `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock wlan`. You cannot specify other than `Restart=no` for a oneshot service. Another note: I had to use `/sbin/udhcpc -i %i` on my particular embedded Linux.